# The way of working of c# main method

Tags: c#, .net

In Java , generally we declare main method as public because it should be availbale out of class for JVM  to execute.

But in c# , we declare main method as private ( default access specifier is private for method in c#). How main method is available to CLR to get executed?

Please forgive me for asking very simple question :)

Answer (score 6):

The CLR doesn't actually mind if your method is private or public.  It doesn't invoke it through the use of normal C# code.In native Call stack,CLR gets to Main method using `.entrypoint IL directive`

Answer (score 1):

Access (Public, Private) modifiers are just for developers to prevent using unwanted methods or members. VM just needs a method to start execute your program regardless of its access modifier.